# How should I dim the header line of inactive windows?

Tags: window, header-line

By analogy to the `mode-line-inactive` face, I'd like to dim the header line for inactive windows.  But I can't find a "header-line-inactive" face, nor can I find an appropriate hook to modify.

I have the following in my init file, so every window gets a header line.

```
(setq-default header-line-format 
              '("%e"
                mode-line-front-space
                mode-line-buffer-identification
                (vc-mode vc-mode)
                mode-line-end-spaces))
```

Comment: Looks like you would need to set the face each time you switch windows. You could do this by advising `select-window`, or perhaps using a `buffer-list-update-hook`.

Comment: Could you specify the `header-line-format` you use? (I need to know it to be able to improve my answer.)

Comment: I didn't know header lines were supported. There's always something new to discover with Emacs!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the face of the header line by setting properties of the text in `header-line-format`, but you would need to update `header-line-format` on every window switch.

As mentioned by @Slomojo, `buffer-list-update-hook` is the hook to use.

You can start with this draft of a hook and adjust the format string and text properties:

```
(defun my-update-header ()
  (mapc
   (lambda (window)
     (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
       (if (eq window (selected-window))
           (setq header-line-format (propertize "selected" 'face 'mode-line))
         (setq header-line-format (propertize "inactive" 'face 'mode-line-inactive)))))
   (window-list)))

(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook #'my-update-header)
```

**Update Nov 14, 2014:**

Here's an extension of the idea used above to arbitrary header formats:

```
(defun my-update-header ()
  (mapc
   (lambda (window)
     (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
       ;; don't mess with buffers that don't have a header line
       (when header-line-format
         (let ((original-format (get 'header-line-format 'original))
               (inactive-face 'warning)) ; change this to your favorite inactive header line face
           ;; if we didn't save original format yet, do it now
           (when (not original-format)
             (put 'header-line-format 'original header-line-format)
             (setq original-format header-line-format))
           ;; check if this window is selected, set faces accordingly
           (if (eq window (selected-window))
               (setq header-line-format original-format)
             (setq header-line-format `(:propertize ,original-format face ,inactive-face)))))))
   (window-list)))
```

I save the original value of `header-line-format` as a property of `header-line-format` so it can be restored later. To change the face of inactive header lines I use [`:propertize`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html#Mode-Line-Data).

This breaks if a buffer is displayed by more than one window, and I am convinced that there is no way to do this right: you can't set different buffer-local values of `header-line-format` in the selected window and the rest of windows displaying the same buffer. (The mode line gets special treatment in the Emacs redisplay code implemented in C.)

Comment: Whoa. `buffer-list-update-hook` is rocking my world. I want to accept this answer, but first could you please clarify: Is there a way to make this work with arbitrary mode line constructs in `header-line-format`?  I've tried and am failing thus far.

Comment: I think I found it on my own. Instead of changing the string properties, I can use `face-remap-add-relative` / `face-remap-remove-relative` in the hook. I don't have it working yet, but it might do. I'm accepting this one on the assumption that I can come back later and edit it to use those functions

Comment: Sorry I had a busy day! I was going to suggest keeping a inactive header line alist and copy it to the inactive buffers.  And an active header line a list you copy to the active buffer.  I'd need to actually try a couple of things to be sure! - nice answer btw

Comment: Thank you constantine. I've one question, what are other `inactive-face` colors i can use, can i define myself, or go through the active theme one like modus-vivendi

Comment: @Constantine , when i c-x-2, then it highlight both . is it bug?

Answer (score 1):

As a fairly incomplete answer (I'm in the bus so I'll flesh it out in a little while.)

You can use the `buffer-list-update-hook`
This hook runs whenever the buffer list changes.

You can then determine which buffer is now current and update the `header-line-format` accordingly.

Comment: Hello can you please explain it. give example . Thank you

Comment: You can see that the first answer does explain it all fully? (I see you commenting on it too, so I guess you decided not to delete the above comment.)